# New line in HTML file rendered as unwanted spacing

Tags: html, html-table, newline

I have HTML table and in it is cell with few anchor tags. Problem is: anchor tags in HTML file - if they are one under another separately by enter - in rendered table is unwanted spacing... If anchors in file are together `<a>one</a><a>two</a>` then spacing disappear...

Is there some way has 'nice' code in file and at the same time has no spacing on rendered table?

```css
table .termin-action-letter {
  display: inline-block;
  /* float: left; */
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<h4>Table #1</h4>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>text text</td>
    <td>
      <a class="termin-action-letter s">S</a>
      <a class="termin-action-letter d">D</a>
      <a class="termin-action-letter dd">DD</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br>
<br>

<h4>Table #2</h4>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>text text</td>
    <td>
      <a class="termin-action-letter s">S</a><a class="termin-action-letter d">D</a><a class="termin-action-letter dd">DD</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1uga2jrt/)

Answer (score 0):

By default, items within `<td></td>` will have some browser specific spacing between them.

You can set the `<td>` style to `display: table-row-group;` to group the `<a>` tags together as one item, rather than separate.

Comment: If i set display:table-row-group on td then tr is not one row anymore http://jsfiddle.net/1uga2jrt/1/